# Cannot import name 'views' from 'website.views' error

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make some sort of websites using Flask, I was trying to import some modules inside the same folder yet it seems like I keep getting this problem.

```
PS D:\Projects\Python\Website tuto> & d:/Files/Python/python.exe "d:/Projects/Python/Website tuto/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Projects\Python\Website tuto\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "d:\Projects\Python\Website tuto\website\__init__.py", line 7, in create_app
    from .views import views
ImportError: cannot import name 'views' from 'website.views' (d:\Projects\Python\Website tuto\website\views.py)
```

Here is my code:
`__init__.py`

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'gezahiyageza2002@'

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    return app
```

`views.py`

```
from flask import Blueprint

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return "<h1>Test</h1>"
```

Comment: Please add a directory tree structure of your code

Answer (score 0):

After trying for some hours, I come to a conclusion that some times if your code doesn't work just try to save your work , quite the editor and open it again . Yep looks stupid but it just worked for me .